# Macbook: keyboard/trackpad disconnect

Tags: usb, keyboard, touchpad, mac, 16.10

This is on a MacBook Pro 2011 running Kubuntu 16.10. Non-proprietary video drivers. Everything up to date as of 6 Dec 2016

Happens randomly. Thought for awhile it was related to Alt+Tab bc that was triggering it with some frequency. But by now I've seen other random, unrelated things cause it - just now I came back from a few hours away from the machine and it wouldn't respond. When it happens, the keyboard and trackpad are gone. I can plug in a mouse or keyboard into the front USB, but only that one works. If I do lsusb, the "Apple, Inc. Keyboard/Trackpad" entry is not listed. Here's the truncated output of dmesg:

> [105113.100079] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlp2s0 Scan_results
>   error (-22) [105176.104060] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlp2s0
>   Scan_results error (-22) [105239.084056] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status
>   : wlp2s0 Scan_results error (-22) [105301.060026] ohci-pci
>   0000:00:06.0: frame counter not updating; disabled [105301.060032]
>   ohci-pci 0000:00:06.0: HC died; cleaning up [105301.060102] usb 4-3:
>   USB disconnect, device number 2 [105301.136210] bcm5974 4-3:1.2: could
>   not read from device [105301.168147] usb 4-5: USB disconnect, device
>   number 3 [105301.208383] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 4
>   [105301.208386] usb 4-6.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
>   [105302.088053] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlp2s0 Scan_results
>   error (-22) [105365.068114] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlp2s0
>   Scan_results error (-22) [105428.108156] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status
>   : wlp2s0 Scan_results error (-22)

There's tons of those ERROR lines before and after the disconnect. I know that bcm5974 is the trackpad device.

So, what can I do to

- A - prevent this from happening
- B - recover so I can save my files,
  etc if I don't happen to have a spare USB keyboard handy

If it helps, lsmod can be found [here](http://jeromio.com/tmp/lsmod.notmac.120616)

Comment: check [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119849/internal-keyboard-and-trackpad-stop-working-after-plugging-in-usb-device) for possible answers.

Comment: Interesting, but not applicable. I don't have any USB devices plugged in, nor have I ever, except for when the keyboard/trackpad stop working.